# Issue with datepicker getting the max date

Tags: jquery, date

I am using the following code to Get the `maxDate` from datepicker but i doesnt seem to work. Can you spot any errors in the code.

```
$('#date_tim').appendDtpicker({
       futureOnly:true,
       autodateOnStart:false,
       minTime:"10:00",
       maxTime:"18:00",
       maxDate : '+3M',
       minDate: 0,
       closeOnSelected: true        
   });
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery-simple-datetimepicker Custom "Future Only"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155799/jquery-simple-datetimepicker-custom-future-only)

Comment: Do you want to set max date 3 moth later from current date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function(){
   myDate = new Date();
   myDate .setMonth(myDate.getMonth()+3);
    $('#date_tim').appendDtpicker({
       futureOnly:true,
       autodateOnStart:false,
       minTime:"10:00",
       maxTime:"18:00",
       maxDate : myDate,
       closeOnSelected: true  
    }); 
});
```

Here is working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gqvxs0wg/1/

> Not : maxDate option have a bug in version  v1.13.0. Although it
>   working fine with version v1.12.0. In version v1.13.0 it will show
>   error on last month of your date range.

To fix that you need to change this line

```
newdate = $picker.data("maxDate");
```

to

```
newdate = new Date($picker.data("maxDate"));
```

at line no 408 in file jquery.simple-dtpicker.js

Answer (score 1):

For setting the date range:

```
$('#date_tim').appendDtpicker({
        maxDate : '2016/11/10',
        minDate: '2016/09/10'        
    });
```

For setting a date you can use the below code:

```
$('#date_tim').handleDtpicker('setDate', new Date(2016, 09, 10, 0, 0, 0));
```

You need to mention whatever date and time you want to set inside the new `Date();`

Answer (score 0):

You use *maxDate* and *minDate* format for [jQuery UI Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). But you use another jQuery plugin ([jquery.simple-dtpicker.js](http://mugifly.github.io/jquery-simple-datetimepicker/jquery.simple-dtpicker.html)). You should set date objects to this options, see example below:

```
$('#date_tim').appendDtpicker({
    futureOnly: true,
    autodateOnStart: false,
    minTime: "10:00",
    maxTime: "18:00",
    minDate: new Date(),
    maxDate: calculateMaxDate(3),
    closeOnSelected: true
});

function calculateMaxDate(monthsCount) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + monthsCount);
    return date;
}
```